# how do I adapt the my application area to the user's monitor resolution?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, scrollbar

how do I adapt the my application area to the user's monitor resolution?

I have created a winForms application on 1280*768 resolution monitor and the application is generally used on smaller laptops (10inches). Now I need to a scrollbar on my entire application so that the spacing remains the same as I have designed. For this, there has to be a scrollbar (Both Horizontal and Vertical) on the application.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Set the form's AutoScroll to True, and set the AutoScrollMinSize to the area you want.  If the form is smaller than the given area, scrollbars will appear.  When you move them the controls will move automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jnm2 but I need to keep my form size same as what I am giving but to add scroll bar in it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I answered it this time.

Comment: Yes that will work. But does works in my case as I have to set the formborderstyle to None.

Comment: Yes. It works on any control implementing IScrollableControl no matter what borders you have - including ordinary controls like panels.